# Find the number of solutions to $x^3 \equiv x \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Rephrasing the question, it is asking to find the number of solutions to $n|x(x+1)(x-1)$

What I have so far is that if $n$ is prime then the solutions are $x = 0, 1, n-1$, and for $n$ is composite I think I first need to find the number of solutions for when $n$ is a prime power and use the CRT to deduce the final solution. I'm stuck on trying to deduce the number of solutions for when $n$ is a prime power, any hints on how to approach it?

Comment: If $ \gcd(n, 2) \neq 2 $, use the fact that $\gcd(x, x+1) = 1, \gcd (x, x-1) = 1, \gcd (x-1, x+1) \leq 2 $ to conclude that either $x, x+1, x-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$. Then deal with $\gcd(n,2) = 2$ separately.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $p>2$ is prime, $p$ could divide $x$, $x-1$, or $x+1$, but not more than one of those

Comment: Not if $\gcd(x,p^k)=1$ then $x^3 \equiv x \iff x^2 \equiv 1$.  Nd if $\gcd(x,p^k)=p^m$ then $x = p^w$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, If $n = 15$, $x = 4,5,6$ are all solutions though.

Comment: Since you mentioned you're stuck on how to deduce the number of solutions when $n$ is a prime power, all the above comments apply to prime powers only. You can their hints and CRT to tackle the problem.

Comment: @McBasketball My statement was in regards to your point of "When $n$ is a prime power, then use CRT", which is the standard approach in such cases. For prime powers  $p^k, p \neq 2$, they contribute $3$ solutions $\mod p^k$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you, my misunderstanding.

Comment: For an example using CRT to compute modular roots of polynomials see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864763/242).